# dataTable - How to set page start correctly?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to get the current page and return date when the page you were on, my update is for ajax.

I can actually get my page by page variable and tell which page that starts "`oTable.fnPageChange(1);`"

However when I use "`oTable.fnPageChange(1);`" starting on page I say but does not show pagination and error in the "`too much recursion`" console

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var page = 0;
    jQuery('#htmlgrid').dataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) { 

                var oTable = jQuery('#htmlgrid').dataTable();
                var totalRows = oTable.fnGetData().length;


                oTable.fnPageChange(1);
                page  = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength);                                    
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

How do I fix this or what is the right way?

Notes: I'm using version 1.11.1 jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed happening `too much recursion`, the problem is due to `drawCallback` being called everytime it is changing the page, in other words, everytime the page changes will enter in function implying in new page change, so will need to re-draw infinitely.

From [docs](http://www.datatables.net/reference/option/):

```
drawCallback:
Function that is called every time DataTables performs a draw.
```

Instead of using `drawCallback` we need to use `initComplete` callback, which will call the function only once:

```
var page = 0;
$('#example').dataTable({
    "initComplete": function (oSettings) { //changed line

        var oTable = this;
        var totalRows = oTable.fnGetData().length;


        oTable.fnPageChange(1);
        page = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength);
    }
});
```

**FIDDLE using example table**: http://jsfiddle.net/6U6ps/

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works but only to refresh the page, I put a test and alert for this alert only works on refresh the page after the ajax call alert works ai n does not change the page I wanted = (

Comment: Will you have a button to change page? You need to explain better what is needed, as it is currently written we can't know requirements

Comment: I have 2 buttons update and search for days when clicked both from a post via ajax in another page that returns json data in that table it is remotando

In this case I'll just use the upgrade after upgrade return the same page

Comment: What I realized that updating the page calls the Initcomplete, but if an update does not call the ajax Initcomplete.

I think I have rechamalo in ajax success

Comment: yes you need to use the initcomplete code inside ajax success too